# How do i handle routing using both angular js and node js (express)?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, routes, mean-stack

I am creating single page application using node,express and angular js. I am not getting  that how to manage routes in both angular and express(node).
Please help me and If possible give some example code or link.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna create a single page application you need to use the router of angular for navigate in your app without reload, but in generally you need data from server, to organise this data you need a route on node.

This is a example of ngRoute

http://plnkr.co/edit/L4Hxf7KiiVuouPWRv4pl

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      template: 'hello'
    })
    .when("/red", {
      template: 'hi'
    })
    .when("/green", {
      templateUrl: 'hello.html'
    })
    .when("/blue", {
      templateUrl: 'blue.html'
    });

});
```

example of node route
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html